# Get login details from login dialog

Tags: javascript, session, authentication

I think I already know my answer but I want to make sure I am correct..

I am using a login dialog which looks like below to login to my GUI in the web browser:

[image]

Just wondering if it's possible to get what username and password that was entered in using JavaScript?

Also, is there a way to kill the session using JavaScript so it will ask for your login details again when a user clicks on a link?

I am guessing this is not possible to be done, but just want to make sure?

Comment: This is a web server based login, and not a web page based login. So the web page including any script are not even loaded yet.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, hypothetically if you have

```
<input id="login"></input>
<input id="password"></input>
<span class="submit"></span>
```

You can save it to a global json object like..

```
var information = {
     username: "",
     password: ""
}
```

And use something like this code to grab it on the click event...

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
     information.username = document.getElementById("login").value;
     information.password = document.getElementById("password").value;
});
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: only thing is there is not input fields on the page as its a popup dialog. otherwise I would of done what you are suggesting.

Comment: what kind of fields are they? or is that what your question is?

Comment: its what my question is.. just wanted to know if there way a way of reading the session details.